# Is there a way of changing Facebook login's (Continue as...) form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

[image]

Is there a way of changing Facebook login's (Continue as...) form css, like button color or anything else?
I am talking about this form, where you are already in facebook domain like `https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=...`
Any help would be appreaciated

Comment: Just an FYI since you were clearly trying to censor your facebook name, you missed one. `Not [name]? Log into another account`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to style or edit the login/authorization popup. Users need to know that they authorize a Facebook App with their login.